Parse nested JSON logs in Grafana Loki (forwarded with Fluentd)
My lab has a few Docker containers as follows:



name
Docker image




Fluentd
fluent/fluentd:v1.16-1


Fluent-bit
cr.fluentbit.io/fluent/fluent-bit


Loki
grafana/loki


Grafana
grafana/grafana-enterprise


Caddy
caddy:builder



My goal is to collect Caddy logs and visualize them in Grafana.
Scenario: Fluent-bit tails the logs and sends them to Fluentd. Then Fluentd pushes the logs to Loki. My aim is to use Fluentd as the central log collector.
The problem is the parsing of those logs Grafana-side.
The Caddy logs are in (nested) JSON format. Sample:

{"level":"info","ts":1712949034.535184,"logger":"http.log.access.log1","msg":"handled request","request":{"remote_ip":"172.18.0.1","remote_port":"39664","client_ip":"172.18.0.1","proto":"HTTP/1.1","method":"POST","host":"grafana.darknet.com","uri":"/api/short-urls","headers":{"Content-Length":["580"],"Origin":["http://grafana.darknet.com"],"Content-Type":["application/json"],"User-Agent":["Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:124.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/124.0"],"Accept":["application/json, text/plain, */*"],"X-Grafana-Org-Id":["1"],"Connection":["keep-alive"],"Accept-Language":["en-US,en;q=0.5"],"Accept-Encoding":["gzip, deflate"],"Referer":["http://grafana.darknet.com/explore?schemaVersion=1&panes=%7B%22Efb%22:%7B%22datasource%22:%22f779c221-7bd2-468d-9f9c-96e069b869f8%22,%22queries%22:%5B%7B%22refId%22:%22A%22,%22expr%22:%22%7Bjob%3D%5C%22caddy.log.loki%5C%22%7D%20%7C%20json%22,%22queryType%22:%22range%22,%22datasource%22:%7B%22type%22:%22loki%22,%22uid%22:%22f779c221-7bd2-468d-9f9c-96e069b869f8%22%7D,%22editorMode%22:%22code%22%7D%5D,%22range%22:%7B%22from%22:%22now-1m%22,%22to%22:%22now%22%7D%7D%7D&orgId=1"],"X-Grafana-Device-Id":["f343e938e74b3a57997faff69d24de8a"],"Cookie":[]}},"bytes_read":580,"user_id":"","duration":0.011267887,"size":72,"status":200,"resp_headers":{"X-Xss-Protection":["1; mode=block"],"Date":["Fri, 12 Apr 2024 19:10:34 GMT"],"Content-Length":["72"],"Server":["Caddy"],"Cache-Control":["no-store"],"Content-Type":["application/json"],"X-Content-Type-Options":["nosniff"],"X-Frame-Options":["deny"]}}

I have tried two different configurations so far:

Have Fluent-bit send the logs to Fluentd, then Fluentd forwards the logs to Loki (tagged as caddy.log)
Schema: Cady --> Fluent-bit --> Fluentd --> Loki

Have Fluent-bit send the logs straight to Loki (tagged as caddy.log.loki)
Schema: Cady --> Fluent-bit --> Loki


Here I have the following Fluent-bit config to send logs to both Loki and Fluentd at the same time, with different tags:
[INPUT]
    Name tail
    Path /var/log/caddy/*.log
    Parser json
    Tag caddy.log
    Path_Key log_filename

# send logs to Fluentd
[OUTPUT]
    Name forward
    Host fluentd
    Port 24224
    Match caddy.*

# send logs straight to Loki
[OUTPUT]
    name                   loki
    match                  caddy.*
    host                   loki
    port                   3100
    labels                 job=caddy.log.loki

Fluentd config:
<source>
  @type  forward
</source>

<match caddy.*>
  @type loki
  url "http://loki:3100"
  extra_labels {"job": "caddy.log"}
  <buffer>
    flush_interval 5s
    flush_at_shutdown true
  </buffer>
</match>

Then in Grafana I can browse the logs and I have the two labels available in the Explore window.
If I choose the tag caddy.log.loki the logs are displayed in plain JSON as shown below. With this expression I can parse them: {job="caddy.log.loki"} | json. Some of the nested JSON is extracted eg: request_client_ip but not all of it, for example request.headers is missing but I can live with that.

If I choose the tag caddy.log then the logs are displayed in a "mixed" format:

It appears that some transformation took place but I am not sure where.
I can use logfmt to parse the lines. But I am still left with some unparsed fields (request, resp_headers) as shown below:

Questions:

why is that the logs are not rendered in plain JSON anymore if I add the Fluentd step?
what would be the best way to ship and parse nested JSON logs in Loki/Grafana with Fluentd?



why is that the logs are not rendered in plain JSON anymore if I add the Fluentd step?

According to the fluentd loki output plugin docs, the default line_format is key_value. You did not specify the format in your fluentd configuration, so the logs are not in JSON but in <key>=<value> format.

what would be the best way to ship and parse nested JSON logs in Loki/Grafana with Fluentd?

You can try adding Nest filter to your fluentbit configuration:
[SERVICE]
    parsers_file    parsers.conf

[INPUT]
    Name        tail
    Path        /var/log/caddy/*.log
    Parser      json
    Tag         caddy.log
    Path_Key    log_filename

[FILTER]
    Name            nest
    Match           caddy.*
    Operation       lift
    Nested_under    request

# Nest filter can be chained
[FILTER]
    Name            nest
    Match           caddy.*
    Operation       lift
    Nested_under    headers
    Add_prefix      req_

[FILTER]
    Name            nest
    Match           caddy.*
    Operation       lift
    Nested_under    resp_headers
    Add_prefix      resp_

# send logs to Fluentd
[OUTPUT]
    Name        forward
    Host        fluentd
    Port        24224
    Match       caddy.*

# send logs straight to Loki
[OUTPUT]
    name                   loki
    match                  caddy.*
    host                   loki
    port                   3100
    labels                 job=caddy.log.loki

Result:

Note that LogQL json parser without parameters will skip arrays (https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/query/log_queries/#json), so if you want fields with arrays you have to specify it in the parameters, for example:
{job="caddy.log.loki"} |= `` | json request_user_agent=`["req_User-Agent"]`



line_format json indeed did the trick. Now the logs are arriving as JSON after being forwarded by Fluentd. The nested JSON is also being parsed partially, for example request_client_ip is available straight out of the box. Extracting the array values like the headers would probably take a few filter and parser steps but I am already happy with what I have. I also added TLS transport between Fluent-bit and Fluentd. Thanks a lot.
